# In html table with jquery search column, get value and delete row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, html-table

HTML:

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
   <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Counter</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th style="display:none;">TypeDistribution</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I add values dynamically properly.

I want to do search and if myValue equals a value in column 3 (TypeDistribution), get the value in the column 1 (Counter) and delete the entire row. Can I do it with jquery and how?

Type is text,
Counter and TypeDistribution are integers,
Remove is button.

Edit:

[image: A small example of the table.]

Comment: What are values for column 1 and column 3 ?

Comment: What exactly you  are searching in that columns?

Comment: I tried to make a search and it works, but i cant make it to do all the actions. JQuery confuses me at this point.
TypeDistribution are numeric values 0 - 9

Comment: Please show some html with values

Comment: This is the second time that i post a question, sorry for the missing info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var searchValue = 456; //lets say your value is 456
    $("table tr").each(function(){
       $(this).find('td').each(function(){
          var currentText = $(this).text();

          if(currentText == searchValue){
              $(this).parents('tr').remove();
          }
      });
   });
});
```

HTML:-

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Counter</th>
      <th>Remove</th>
      <th style="display:none;">TypeDistribution</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>def</td>
      <td>ghi</td>
      <td>pqr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
      <td>789</td>
      <td>101</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works for me. I wonder, why it is not working. Just make sure your Script should be in `$(document).ready()`. And Your Jquery library should be included before to that. If possible can you please tell what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Just give your third column a class, for example `typeDistribution`. The you can easily access it and, going over its parents, also the other columns.

```
/**
 * Compare the given value with the third column
 * @param  {String} value The value to compare the thrd column with
 * @return {String}       The value from the first column
 */
function compare(value) {
    if ($('.typeDistribution').html() == value) {
        return $(this).parent().remove().children()[1].html();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have to use an `each` loop, I am not quite sure now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.table .values').each(function() {
      $('td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == $(".select option:selected").val()) {
          var old = $('tr').find("td").eq(1).text();
          $('tr').find("td").eq(1).text(parseInt(old) + 1);
        } else {
          alert('not found');
        }
      })
    });
  });
})
```